# no wifi after upgrade to 15.04 (no interface showing) bcm4313

Tags: wireless

I just upgraded to 15.04 and now the network connection icon shows but there is no wifi in the network options. This is on a hp dm1 bcm4313.

```
ifconfig only shows "eth1" and "lo" 
iwconfig says no wireless
```

running kernel 3.19.0-17

I tried this:

```
HP-Pavilion-dm1-Notebook-PC:~$ lshw -C network

WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0200000-f0203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 06
       serial: 80:c1:6e:5a:45:30
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0104000-f0104fff memory:f0100000-f0103fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

then I followed this thread :

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2277063

and the adapter now recognizes wifi networks BUT the connection is extremely slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can it be runnin kernel 3.13, if you have Ubuntu 15.04? Kernel 3.19 should be there.

Comment: Pilot6: you are right!  my kernel is 3.19. I will update it! I was looking at another laptop, guess I got confused!

Comment: User68186: I did not follow any of that. My problem started with me not seeing the wifi card.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the driver of your WiFi card.

If you can connect to internet via cable then go to Dash > Softwares Sources > Additional Drivers, and you should see the driver of your WiFi card: enable it, and you're done.

If you have no cable then you should mount the Ubuntu ISO Image (right click on the image > open with disk image mounter). From the mounted image root, go to pool/restricted/b and double click on the package there. The software installer will pop up, click install and restart once finished. You should now be able to see the wlan0 interface.

Answer (score 0):

ok so here is what I did (not yet solved!):

I had signal and networks showing but slow connection so I un-blacklisted the bcma driver and blacklisted all of the following:

sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

mac80211
brcm80211
cfg80211
wl
lib80211_crypt_tkip
lib80211

And now I still have a problem...
after coming out of suspend I have to do the purge, then reinstall the driver. does anyone have any ideas about what command i need to use to keep my present installation and not have to constantly redo it?